# Split a list and create partitions(list) depending upon the unique set of values

Tags: python, list

deck = `[1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]`

Output: `True`

Explanation: Possible partition `[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]`.

Input: `deck = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]`

Output: `False`

Explanation: No possible partition.

The solution i tried was very , very basic but  i couldn't solve further than this. P.S:I am starting my coding experience.

```
v=[1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
t=list()
flag=0
for i in v:
    t.append(v.count(i))
for i in range(len(t)):
    for j in range(len(t)):
        if(t[i]==t[j]):
            flag=0
        else:
            flag=1
if(flag==1):
    print("NO")
else:
    q=len(list(set(v)))
    n = q
    lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're trying to do here. What do "possible partition" and "no possible partition" mean? What's the goal? How does your current solution fail? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]` can be split into `[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3]` right

Comment: maybe every partition has to be the same size otherwise you can’t do it. OP hasn’t clarified that though

Comment: The count should be the same , '1':3,'2':3,'3':3 else no partition is created.A single element with count different , it won't create the partition.

Comment: use itertools.groupby and check if each group is the same size, most straightforward way to achieve this

Comment: or a `Counter` and check that all counts are the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

How it works - It goes through all the list and stores the occurrence of each value. Then It makes of a set of it. Returns true if length of set is 1 i.e every number appears exactly the same number of times.

EDIT - set has a property that its element dont repeat. So say if the value of `dikt` is `{1: 3, 2:3, 3:3}` then the value of `dikt.values` is `[3,3,3]`. Making a set out of it will be `(3)`. 
IF the value of `dikt` was `{1:3, 2:3, 3:2}` then the set would be `(3, 2)`

```
def foo(x):

    dikt = {}

    for i in x:

        if i in dikt.keys():
            dikt[i]+=1
        else:
            dikt[i] = 1

    return len(set(dikt.values())) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` here.

```
from collections import Counter
def partition(lst):
    count=Counter(lst)
    if len(set(count.values()))>1:
        return 'No partition'
    else:
        return [[i]*n for i,n in count.items()]
```

---

```
deck = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
partition(deck)
#[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
deck=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
partition(deck)
#'No partition found'
```

---

If you just want the output to be `True` or `False` try this.

```
def partition(lst):
    return len(set(Counter(lst).values()))==1
```